# TRUE/FALSE ← VLOOKUP ← Identify the ROW! of the first negative value within a column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Firstly, we have an array of predetermined factors, ie. V-Z;
their attributes are 3, the first two (•xM) multiplied giving the 3rd.

f ... factors
• ... cap, the values in the data set may increase max
m ... fixed multiplier
p ... let's call it power

This is a separate, standalone array .. we'd access with eg. VLOOKUP

f • m pwr
V 1 9 9
W 2 8 16
X 3 7 **21**
Y 4 6 24
Z 5 5 25

—————————————————————————————————————————————

Then we have 6 columns, in which the actual data to be processed is in, & thereof derive the next-level result, based on the interaction of both samples introduced.

In addition, there are added two columns, for balance & profit.

Here's a short, 6-row data sample:

f • m bal profit
V 2 3 377 1
Y 2 3 156 7
Y 1 1 122 0
***X*** 1 2 **-27** 2
Z 3 3 223 3

—————————————————————————————————————————————

Ultimately, starting at the end, we are comparing IF **-27** inverted → so 27 is within the ***X***'s power range ie. **21** (as per the first sample) .. which is then fed into a bigger formula, beyond the scope of this post.

This can be done with VLOOKUP, all fine by now.

—————————————————————————————————————————————

To get to that .. for the working example, we are focusing coincidentally on row5, since that's the one with the first negative value in the 'balance' column, so ..

on factor***X*** = which factor exactly is to us unknown &
balance **-27** = which we have to locate amongst potentially dozens to hundreds of rows.

Why!?

Once we know that the factor is ***X***, based on the * & multiplier pertaining to it, then we also know which 'power' (top array) to compare **-27**, as the identified first negative value in the balance column, to.

Is that clear?

I'd like to know the formula on how to achieve that, & (get to) move on with the broader-scope work.

—————————————————————————————————————————————

The main issue for me is not knowing how to identify the first negative or row **-27** pertains to, then having that piece of information how to leverage it to get the ***X*** or identify the factor type, especially since its positioned left of the latter & to the best of my knowledge I cannot use negative column index number (so, latter even if possible is out of the question anyway).

To recap;

IF(21>27) = IF(-21<-27)
27 → LOCATE ROW with the first negative number (-27)
21 → IDENTIFY the FACTOR TYPE, same row as (-27)
→ VLOOKUP pwr, based on factor type identified (top array, 4th column right)
→ invert either 21 to a negative number or (-27) to the positive number
= TRUE/FALSE

Comment: Excel and Google Sheets are two entirely different products, and they are not entirely compatible. Please tag only with the one that you're actually using, and remove the tags for the product that you are not actually using. Tag-spamming is highly discouraged here, and is a very good way to quickly get your post closed and downvoted.

Comment: Hello, you have a lot of information and it's easy to get lost. Specifically you need to identify the first row with a negative value in Balance?

Comment: @Martin yes, that's the first step .. let's start with that.

Comment: Thereof we pivot on the 'row number' .. getting the factor type (above case scenario X).

Comment: We can then VLOOKUP the power attribute (pertaining to X), & finally -- compare it with the initial cell we've identified the row of .. now inverted to a positive number  =IF(21>27).

Comment: Create a helper column, containing something like `=IF(OR(A2<0, B2<0, ...),-1,+1)` and find the minimum for that column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guessing your columns I'll say your first chart is in columns A to D, and the second in columns G to K

You could find the letter of that factor with something like this:

```
=INDEX(G:G,XMATCH(TRUE,INDEX(J:J<0)))
```

`INDEX(J:J<0)` converts that column to TRUE and FALSE depending on being negative or not and with XMATCH you find the first TRUE. You could then use that in VLOOKUP:

```
=VLOOKUP(INDEX(G:G,XMATCH(TRUE,INDEX(J:J<0))),A:D,4,0)
```

That would return the 21. You can use the first concept too to find the the -27 and with ABS have its "positive value"

```
=VLOOKUP(INDEX(G:G,XMATCH(TRUE,INDEX(J:J<0))),A:D,4,0) > INDEX(J:J,XMATCH(TRUE,INDEX(J:J<0)))
```

That should return true or false in the comparison

Comment: Turns out XMATCH ain't supported by WPS -- how to restructure the formula to achieve the same with MATCH alone or combined with something?

Comment: Change that part with `MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(J:J<0),0)`

Comment: https://ibb.co/B4HhVP2

Comment: Seems the syntax is incorrect .. I've tried various other options of it, adding coma & "<0" as well, none gets accepted.

Comment: The issue was with the tagging. Originally it was in Google Sheets, it would possibly work with Excel but not with WPS